# SQL Server query that uses 2 different indexes returning fields by Doc Number line and then separate lines with fields by client information

Tags: sql, sql-server, sapb1

I would like to write a query that will pull a doc number and some other associated fields in one line then on the next few lines pull names and email addresses associated with that doc number. Here is an image to reference why I am talking about.

[image]

So far my code gives me the correct results my main issue is I can't figure out how to get the results to "combine" for a lack of a better term. So that the top line is part of the bottom few lines when being displayed. So what my current query is pulling is below. Is there a way I can accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated thank you. My code is below that last image.

[image]

```
SELECT 
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY DocNum) AS 'Row', 
    T2.DocNum, T2.DocStatus, T1.ItemCode, T1.Description, 
    T1.SerialNum, T2.CardName, T3.Name, T3.E_MailL, T3.EmlGrpCode, 
    T4.CountryB, T4.StateB, T2.DocDueDate 
INTO 
    #Temptbl
FROM
    OITM T0
LEFT JOIN 
    DLN1 T1 WITH (NOLOCK) ON T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
LEFT JOIN 
    ODLN T2 WITH (NOLOCK) ON T1.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
LEFT JOIN
    OCPR T3 WITH (NOLOCK) ON T2.CardCode = T3.CardCode
LEFT JOIN
    DLN12 T4 WITH (NOLOCK) ON T2.DocEntry = T4.DocEntry
WHERE 
    T0.ItemCode = 'VT900785-4'
         
DECLARE @Id int
DECLARE @DNum int

WHILE EXISTS(SELECT * FROM #Temptbl)
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP 1 @id = Row FROM #Temptbl

    SELECT DISTINCT @DNum = DocNum 
    FROM #Temptbl 
    WHERE Row = @id

    SELECT DISTINCT 
        DocNum, DocStatus, ItemCode, Dscription, SerialNum, CardName, 
        CountryB, StateB, DocDueDate 
    FROM
        #Temptbl 
    WHERE 
        Row = @id

    SELECT 
        Name, E_MailL, EmlGrpCode 
    FROM
        #Temptbl 
    WHERE
        DocNum = @DNum

    DELETE #Temptbl 
    WHERE DocNum = @DNum   
END

DROP TABLE #Temptbl
```

Comment: [Bad habits : Putting NOLOCK everywhere](https://www.sentryone.com/blog/aaronbertrand/bad-habits-nolock-everywhere)

Comment: Two strange things with this query 1. If you interleave the parent and child rows then the column names don't make sense, and it strikes me that this is something that should be done by the presentation layer 2. If `T2.DocNum` is effectively the parent row, why would you left join it, wouldn't you want an inner join? And if it is the PK, why use `distinct` when you will always get back one row?

Comment: This is trivial to do in any reporting tool - which is where a task like this is best implemented. And if you need a cursor, then just USE A CURSOR! Your <while loop over a temp table using a sequential ID> is simply a more error-prone and slower version of that.

Answer (score 0):

This should do what you want, although it's a really strange thing to do. The column names are not going to make much sense.

```sql
select
    ISNULL(T3.Name, T2.DocNum),
    ISNULL(T3.E_MailL, T1.Dscription), 
    ISNULL(T3.EmlGrpCode, T1.ItemCode),
    T2.DocStatus,
    T1.SerialNum,
    T2.CardName,
    T4.CountryB,
    T4.StateB,
    T2.DocDueDate 
from OITM T0
join DLN1 T1 on T0.ItemCode = T1.ItemCode
Join ODLN T2 on T1.DocEntry = T2.DocEntry
left join DLN12 T4 on T2.DocEntry = T4.DocEntry
cross join (values(0),(1)) v(IsChild)
left join OCPR T3 on T2.CardCode = T3.CardCode AND v.IsChild = 1
Where T0.ItemCode = 'VT900785-4'
ORDER BY T2.DocNum, v1.IsChild
```

Comment: I guess I didn't explain this well. I need my query to look like the second picture I posted which is my query being ran, but formatted better so it looks like:Line 1- doc number and other info
Line 2- Client name and other info associated with docnum
Line 3- other client name and other info associated with docnum
Line 4- other client name and other info associated with docnum
Line 5- doc number and other info
Line 6- Client name and other info associated with docnum
Line 7- other client name and other info associated with docnum
This is hard to explain what I need sorry